# Integrating $(2x+1)^{-2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I integrate the following expression:

$$(2x+1)^{-2}$$

I should end up with something like this:

$$\frac{-1}{2(2x+1)}$$

Comment: Have you tried a substitution?

Comment: You need to look up integration by substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $u=2x+1$, i.e. $du=2dx$

Then
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac 1{(2x+1)^2}dx&=\int\frac 1{2u^2}\cdot du\\
&=-\frac 1{2u}\\
&=-\frac 1{2(2x+1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: @MathGod - Thanks for the comment and edit.